# zend framework 2 get locale from view PhpRenderer

Tags: internationalization, zend-framework2, zend-view, zend-translate, zend-locale

How I can obtain traslator locale in my view?

I want to do it starting from the variable $this (the PhpRenderer of the view).
i.e. I don't want use onBootstrap nor ActionController because I don't care to have a view variables.

Thank you!

Comment: If you don't care for certain stuff, please provide your use-case, too. Since that may influence the answer. tbp: what exactly do you want to do?

Answer (score 3):

You should try:

```
<?php echo \Locale::getDefault(); ?>
```

Many of the I18n classes make reference to PHP's Locale class (http://www.php.net/locale) - so in my opinion that would be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo $this->plugin('translate')->getTranslator()->getLocale(); ?>
```

See:
[Get local value in layout or view in Zend Framework 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20088050/get-local-value-in-layout-or-view-in-zend-framework-2)